# Create header on two different cells iOS

Tags: ios, swift

[image: "On Sale and newly added" have been done. I need "home and living" header.]My question is, I have two different cells on a single tableview. And I want to show the HeaderSection on table. From first cell, I created 2 cells with header also (Done). But from the second cell, I am not able to set it's header. How to do that. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: But My cells are different because I have different uiTableViewCell classes. Beacuse both designs are different.

Comment: Edit your question and post a screenshot or something for how it should be and how it looks now.

Comment: I edit my question. Please look at it. And please suggest me something, because I am not getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method of `UITableView` `viewForHeaderInSection`. make use of it. Here is how you can give a try:

```
switch section {
case 0: //your first cell
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "defaultReuseIdentifier your cell") as! RecommendationTableCellHeaderView
    //populate your headerView
    return headerView

case 1:// your second cell
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "defaultReuseIdentifier your cell") as! RecommendationTableCellHeaderView
    //populate your headerView
    return headerView

default:preconditionFailure()
}
```

Comment: But My cells are different because I have different uiTableViewCell classes. Beacuse both designs are different.

Comment: post requirement as image or code you have used then only we can guide you to the correct answer

Comment: you can deque different UITableViewCell classes for different sections.